# Is using .data() to retrieve the value of data-* attributes a good idea?

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

In my project I am currently using some custom data-* attributes in my HTML to convey some extra data that will be used by jQuery. I found the `.data()` method and noticed that if I have a data-* attribute `data-my-attribute` that I can retrieve its value in jQuery by selecting the element with the attribute and calling `.data("my-attribute")`.

I assumed that this was the way it is supposed to be used (did not look into the documentation) and used it through out my jQuery code. However, now I noticed that when I put for example a string `"000005643"` in the HTML data-* attribute, `.data("my-attribute")` return `5643` while `.attr("data-my-attribute")` return `"000005643"`. Where the latter is what I wanted. This led me to look up the documentation and actually found out that there is more to `.data()` than I thought. Also, I never saw any text or example that indicates you should use `.data()` to retrieve values of data-* attributes. This worries me that I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

So should I cease and desist with using `.data()` in this manner or not? If not, could you link me to some documentation about the `.data()` function that explains this use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method returning HTML5 `data-*` attributes was [introduced in 1.4.3](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/16/jquery-143-released/).

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object.
>
> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

It appears jQuery is certain you want a number, so it is returning a `Number` for you, not the `String`.

If you want it as a string, use `attr()`.

Comment: ah, ok thanks. So if I understand correctly, I should never use `.data()` if I am expecting a `string`. Otherwise I constantly have to worry if it will be converted and information is lost (like the leading zeros). For example a phone number, 063425346.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually working on porting this functionality to Zepto. Yeah, it's not really something wrong with the data- HTML spec but it's just jQuery's implementation of it. It's trying to work around the fact that data- doesn't handle non-strings very well and then it tries to be fancy and pull out values like null, ints, and floats for you. I suppose a workaround is putting a string character in front of your value and substr'ing it off when you retrieve it. Either that or use attr('data-') - though going back and forth between .data and .attr could lead to different results as you've noticed. Stick with one or the other.